# R - Dplyr - Duplicates and expand.grid()

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to remove 'duplicates' from the following:

```
v <- c('Jasper', 'Alice')
w <- c('Jasper', 'Alice')

vw <- expand.grid(v = v, w = w)
```

For the sake of simplicity, I'm filtering the result excluding rows where v and w are equal. Like this:

```
vw <- vw %>% filter(v != w)
```

The result is a 2x2 `data.frame`. When running the code, the values of v and w for the first and the second row are inverted - Jasper Alice rather than Alice Jasper. While they are not, strictly speaking, duplicates I would like to consider them as such. In other words, I only want to retain one of them. I tried with the `duplicated()` function but I couldn't make it work. Is there a `dplyr` (or something else) function that can help with this?

**Note** that this is a simplified example and name vectors are much longer.

Comment: Just to confirm, what you want is for row [2] "Alice Jasper" and row [3] "Jasper Alice" to be considered the same and for only one of them to be kept?

Comment: `utils::combn(c(v,w), m = length(v)) %>% t %>% as.data.frame ` ??

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. I made the edit to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, you need to create another key column where column `v` and `w` are sorted and pasted. You can then use `distinct(key)` on that column to keep only one. Add `%>% select(v,w)` to get only your orginal columns.

```
vw %>%
filter(v != w)   %>%
mutate(key = paste0(pmin(v, w), pmax(v, w), sep = ""))%>%
distinct(key)
      v      w         key
1 Alice Jasper AliceJasper
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can sort by rows with `apply` and then use `duplicated`:

```
vw <- expand.grid(v = v, w = w, stringsAsFactors = F)
vw[!duplicated(t(apply(vw, 1, sort))),]
       v      w
1 Jasper Jasper
2  Alice Jasper
4  Alice  Alice
```